# Keyboard aware scroll view takes up screen space

Tags: css, react-native

I am implementing [React Native Scroll View](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view) to handle the keyboard in my application layout, it works great but it is adding extra "padding" or whitespace below my components.

[image]

It is already styled with `flex: 1` to take all the screen space. Here's the `jsx` code for `App.js`

```js
    <PaperProvider>
      <StatusBar
        barStyle="dark-content"
        hidden={false}
        backgroundColor="#00BCD4"
        translucent={true}
      />
      <KeyboardAwareScrollView
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
      >
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <UnitCard />
          <UnitCard />
          <Converter />
        </View>
      </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
    </PaperProvider>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center",
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#eee",
  },
  cards: {
    flex: 1,
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

Comment: Setting the scrollEnabled prop of the <KeyboardAwareScrollView> to false does the trick: scrollEnabled={false}, so in total <KeyboardAwareScrollView scrollEnabled={false}>...</KeyboardAwareScrollView>

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who comes later, the contentContainerStyle - not the style itself - should have flex: 1 and then it should work.

```
  <KeyboardAwareScrollView
    contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}
  >
```

Comment: `<KeyboardAwareScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}><View style={{flexGrow:1}}>{/* content here */}</View></KeyboardAwareScrollView>` took up the entire screen for me!

Answer (score 2):

Seems to have worked with the following code.

```js
<KeyboardAwareScrollView
        style={{ backgroundColor: "#4c69a5" }}
        resetScrollToCoords={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.container}
        scrollEnabled={false}
        style={{ height: Dimensions.get("window").height }}
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
      >
... components
<KeyboardAwareScrollView/>
```

Taken from https://medium.com/free-code-camp/how-to-make-your-react-native-app-respond-gracefully-when-the-keyboard-pops-up-7442c1535580

Comment: [SOLVED]: Setting the scrollEnabled prop of the <KeyboardAwareScrollView> to false does the trick: scrollEnabled={false}

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `flex:1` will work in your `KeyboardAwareScrollView` or event in default React Native `ScrollView`

If you want to make it wrap all of your screen height, my suggestion is:

```
const SCREEN_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get("screen").height;

<KeyboardAwareScrollView
    style={{ height: SCREEN_HEIGHT }}
>
....
```

Comment: Neither `Dimensions.get("screen").height` nor `Dimensions.get("window").height` seem to work.